# how to pass double value as a command line argument in java program

Tags: java

Below is my program

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //String str = scanner.nextLine();
    String str=args[0];
    try{
        BigDecimal dec=new BigDecimal(str);
      System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(str)+"\t"+str);

        if(dec.intValue()==dec.doubleValue()){
            System.out.println("This input is of type Integer.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("This input is of type Float.");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("This input is of type string.");
    }

   }
}
```

I want to pass float value as a command line argument. I am passing value 0.00057 as an argument. But it is getting converted to 000057. Can anyone please suggest me.

Comment: How are you passing it to your program?

Comment: Strange, here is my output: `5.7E-4 0.00057 This input is of type Float.`

Comment: You should surround your arguments with double quotes `"0.00057"`.

Comment: It's really strange. I have checked the same in the online IDE in many websites and I was not getting a proper answer.

Comment: @MichaelDz I have done that as well. But still java is automatically converting it to integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something going wrong when you are converting from string to number, to make sure it works define the decimal separator:

```
   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
   DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
   symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
   df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
   Number n = df.parse(str);

   System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(str)+"\t"+str);

   if(n.intValue()==n.doubleValue()){
       System.out.println("This input is of type Integer.");
   }else{
       System.out.println("This input is of type Float.");
   }
```